# Python-Replace HTTP parameters one at a time

Tags: python, html, http

fairly new to Python and hit a stumbling block on a project I am working on.  I am writing a QA testing tool for a web application in Python.  Basically what I need to do is take a simple link with parameters that looks something like this:

```
http://www.something.com/index.html?field1=something&field2=something&field3=something
```

And replace each parameter one at a time while leaving the other parameters intact, and get a response from the web server (i.e. first we would set field1 to a different value, field 2 and 3 would stay as their original values.  Then we would change field2 to a separate value, and field 1 and 3 would stay as their original values).  I started with breaking the full link breaking it apart into multiple lists (one with the path to the page and one with the parameters, one with the parameter names, and one with the values), but I can't get anything working to put it back together into the full link to pass back to the web server.  So my question is am I even close to being on the right path? Is there a way to do this in an easier fashion with httplib or urllib? Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When dealing with HTTP it's much nicer to use the [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) library, then straight-forward to have a `dict` of your parameters, then modify the `dict` and make another request, eg:

```
URL = 'http://www.something.com/index.html?'
params = {'field1': 'something': 'field2': 'something', 'field3': 'something'}

import requests
r = requests.get(URL, params=params)
params['field2'] = 'something else'
r = requests.get(URL, params=params)
```

Alternatively, use Python's builtins:

```
import urllib, urllib2
page = urllib2.urlopen(URL + urllib.urlencode(params))
```

Comment: Worked perfect, tanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

I can give you a very simple solution.

Suppose first you have value of field1 from 'something' to 'thisthing', then field2 from 'something' to 'thatthing', then field3 from 'something' to 'thosething', then do this:

```
>>> import string
>>> xx='http://www.something.com/index.html?field1=something&field2=something&field3=something'
>>> yy=xx.split('field')
>>> yy
['http://www.something.com/index.html?', '1=something&', '2=something&', '3=something']
>>> yy[1]='1=thisthing&'
>>> yy
['http://www.something.com/index.html?', '1=thisthing&', '2=something&', '3=something']
>>> zz='field'.join(yy)
>>> zz
'http://www.something.com/index.html?field1=thisthing&field2=something&field3=something'
```

First step completed, but we didn't changes xx, so for second step you can this same code, only

```
yy[1]='1=thisthing&'
```

will be replaced by

```
yy[2]='1=thatthing&'
```

I wanted to explain everything that I am doing, the actual code is just this:

```
import string
xx='http://www.something.com/index.html?field1=something&field2=something&field3=something'
yy=xx.split('field')
yy[1]='1=thisthing&'
zz='field'.join(yy)
print(zz)
```